# Migrate data from postgresql 8.4 to postgresql 9.4 in 2 different servers

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-cluster

I have a problem with postgresql as below:
I have a server CentOS 5.9 install postgresql 8.4. It is running for my production and Data Size = 300 GB. At the moment, I need migrate all data in postgresql 8.4 to postgresql 9.4 in different server CentOS 6.6.
I use method dumpall data from postgresql 8.4 and restore to postgres 9.4 but the downtime is very long and I canceled this method.
Can you help me guide the method to migrate data in my case to the downtime is shortest?

Thanks you very much.

Comment: Take a look in http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/pgupgrade.html

Answer (score 1):

Migration plan:

1) Upgrade your PG on production server. For **fast** upgrade use pg_upgrade with -k option (WARNING!!! Read manual http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/pgupgrade.html)

2) After upgrade PG setup replication from prod to new server.

3) Promote replica as new PG.

Profit.

Comment: How to replicate data from postgresql 8.4 to postgresql 9.4 Alexander Vasylev?

Comment: Upgrade first (see 1 step above).